# Referring to dynamic members of C# 'dynamic' object

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net

I'm using JSON.NET to deserialize a JSON file to a `dynamic` object in C#.

Inside a method, I would like to pass in a `string` and refer to that specified attribute in the dynamic object.

For example:

```
public void Update(string Key, string Value)
    {
        File.Key = Value;
    }
```

Where `File` is the dynamic object, and `Key` is the string that gets passed in. Say I'd like to pass in the key "foo" and a value of "bar", I would do:
`Update("foo", "bar");`, however due to the nature of the `dynamic` object type, this results in

```
{
 "Key":"bar"
}
```

As opposed to:

```
{
 "foo":"bar"
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm asking here with the dynamic object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* you could use:

```
public void Update(string key, string Value)
{
    File[key] = Value;
}
```

That depends on how the dynamic object implements indexing, but if this is a Json.NET `JObject` or similar, I'd expect that to work. It's important to understand that it's not guaranteed to work for general `dynamic` expressions though.

If you only ever actually need this sort of operation (at least within the class) you might consider using `JObject` as the field type, and then just exposing it as `dynamic` when you need to.

Comment: You are indeed correct, I beat you to it by about 3 seconds :)

Comment: @SeanMissingham: See the end of my answer for a suggestion about making this clearer though.

Comment: Just saw that, thanks! Will mark this one as answer due to best explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so it turns out I'm special. Here's the answer for those that may stumble across this in future,

Turns out you can just use the key like an array index and it works perfectly. So:

`File[Key] = Value;` Works the way I need as opposed to
`File.Key = Value;`

Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's really a notable difference between c# and JavaScript: In JavaScript file.Foo and file["Foo"] are aequivalent. C# has adopted this, but in an inconsistent way as it seems. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33808136/1016343) answer for a comparison of different declarations which will work (and which not).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, if you're using `JObject` from JSON.NET. It does not work with an `ExpandoObject`.

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    var j = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
    var key = "myKey";
    var value = "Hello World!";
    j[key] = value;
    Console.WriteLine(j["myKey"]);
}
```

This simple example prints "Hello World!" as expected. Hence

```
var File = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
public void Update(string key, string Value)
{
    File[key] = Value;
}
```

does what you expect. If you would declare `File` in the example above as

```
dynamic File = new ExpandoObject();
```

you would get a runtime error:

> CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ExpandoObject'